# Python Scraping: Is there anyway that I can scrape this line of code using beautifulsoup? (Finding content of a tag that contain specific tag/string)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Assume the source code is as below:

```
<tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr><td class="field2 mcFont" style="width: 220px; vertical-align:top">PE<div class="icon-edu icon-general-terms" style="display:none" data-key="PE Ratio"></div></td><td class="mcFont cls">7.18</td></tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr>
```

Hi! I am trying to use beautifulsoup to scrape a specific line of code within the table row tr tag (please see below the final result I want to achieve), but since the tr tag does not contain any attributes like other tag while there are millions of tr tags within the page, is there anyway that I could use soup.find_all("tr") to scrape the content of all tr tag that includes td tag with string "PE" or class="field2 mcFont" within it?

The final result I want to achieve:

```
<td class="field2 mcFont" style="width: 220px; vertical-align:top">PE<div class="icon-edu icon-general-terms" style="display:none" data-key="PE Ratio"></div></td><td class="mcFont cls">7.18</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for a tag `<td>` with text "PE" and next `<td>` tag (it's value), you can use:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr><td class="field2 mcFont" style="width: 220px; vertical-align:top">PE<div class="icon-edu icon-general-terms" style="display:none" data-key="PE Ratio"></div></td><td class="mcFont cls">7.18</td></tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr> ... </tr><tr>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

pe = soup.find(lambda t: t.name == "td" and "PE" == t.text).find_next("td")
print(pe.text)
```

Prints:

```
7.18
```

---

Or with CSS selector:

```py
pe = soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("PE") + td')
print(pe.text)
```